# Do Some Process And Download File .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task

I wanna create an excel , save it and download it. But while the excel file is being created , I want the user to should do different processes. That's my controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateExcel() {

        var path = string.Empty;

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            path = SaveExcel();
        });

        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{path}.xls"),
            System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,$"{Guid.NewGuid()}.xls");

    }

private string SaveExcel() {
        //this method will create an excel File and will return the file's path.
    }
```

but when I jump to another URL , the download is being cancelled.

Comment: Just using `async` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()` doesn't parallelize your application. It just helps the server to optimize resource usage. You should think of using async javasript calls from the frontend and poll for the response or use tools like SignalR to react on finishing the excel creation and download later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parallel your application like that. If you want to allow a user to do other things, while Excel is generating, I want to suggest you this way.

Open new popup with the text "Please wait, your Excel is generating" and in this popup, you can make GET call to your controller action. Meantime, user will be able to browse website in the main window

```
 <a id="generateExcel">Generate excel for me</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#generateExcel').click(function() {
            var url = '{LINK_TO_YOUR_CREATE_EXCEL_URL}';
            var newWindow = window.open('', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=500,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
            newWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body>Please wait, your excel is generating<script>window.location='"+url+"'</script></body></html>");
            newWindow.document.close();
            return false;
        })
    })  
</script>
```

Comment: It worked for me , so can I take a warning when download process finished?

Comment: Okey Mr. , it's enough for me , I realized that on Web Projects , if you do a download , you should do  processes on new tab.